# android keyboard open issue

Tags: android

How can i know if the keyboard is open or not?

Answer (score 5):

This is available on the [`Configuration`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) class. You can get the current `Configuration` via `getResources().getConfiguration()` from your `Activity` or other `Context`.

Comment: i have checked this on 4.0 and higher version api 16 but it always show me value 1 means keyboard opened i have added  int hard= config.keyboardHidden; on button click event but always get 1 value why any idea

Answer (score 0):

That way =)

```
public boolean isKeyboardVisible(){
 // Checks whether a hardware keyboard is visible
 if (getResources().getConfiguration().hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
     return true;
 } else if (getResources().getConfiguration()..hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
     return false;
 }
}
```